# WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb, headless-browser

Complete error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at
>   point (931, 23). Other element would receive the click:

Running selenium tests using Jenkins in headless browser
In following environment

> OS- CentOS 6 and Xvfb installed in same machine
>
> Xvfb screen resolution -   Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
>
> Driver - Firefox driver
>
> Selenium webdriver version - 2.52.0

The same test case working fine in windows os with firefox

Comment: Another element on the page is covering the element you are trying to click. The stacktrace will tell you what element it is so you can work your way around it.

Comment: please edit your question and add code formatting to html element (dont know why but, SO dont show it in error message).

Comment: Did you tried running this test in real browser on the same rosolution?

Comment: Does screen resolution impact selenium? Are you using XPATHS?

Comment: Did you try maximizing the screen? definitely problem with your screen resolution, because it works in windows as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Install Xvfb plugin on Jenkins.
After that install Xvfb in "Global Tool Configuration"

[image]

Then under your project configuration, setup xvfb

[image]

Try Using resolution given in image

Now run your build :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason it is important to test on different browsers and on different platforms. Sometimes what works on one browser/os does not work on the same browser but a different platform.

I would update your setup so that you make a screenshot when you run into this type (and most other types) of error. In my experience this is the single best thing you can do to reduce the time spent to debug these issues.

In my setup I do the following:

- Create a screenshot
- Capture the coordinates from the Selenium error message
- Use an image manipulation program to automatically create a red dot where the click happened

Usually I just have to take one look at such an image to see exactly what is happening.