# Protractor tests randomly get Element is not clickable at point

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I keep getting [this error](http://pastebin.com/9iJQwuk5) randomly while running the protractor tests (1 out of 6 or 1 out of 3 for other people in my team) "Element is not clickable at point".

This is how my specs look like

```
 describe('My suite that breaks', function(){
        it('sp start page', function() {
            //some other stuff
        });
        it('select something from dropdown', function(){
            waitForElement(by.css('button[data-organization="none"]')).click();
            waitForElement(by.css('a[data-organization="somevalue"]')).click();
            //some other stuff
        });
```

Some utilitary function defined some other place

```
waitForElement(locator, timeout = config.timeouts.wait){
    var elem = element(locator);
    var isClickable = protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elem);
    browser.wait(isClickable, timeout, 'Waiting for element  \'' + locator + '\' timed out');
    return elem;
}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn-dropdown inner-shadow" data-organization="none">
  Some butt text<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#" class="no-selection" data-organization="none">None</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-organization="something">Something</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This happens randomly. It is not an [xvfb issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008970/webdriverexception-element-is-not-clickable-at-point) since I have full Ubuntu desktop. [The item is viewable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29536768/1387563), [no overlay, no refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error).

```
$cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5
$node --version
v6.8.0
$npm list -g|grep protractor
└─┬ protractor@4.0.9
$webdriver-manager status
[13:49:58] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 2.53.1 [default]
[13:49:58] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.22 [default]
[13:49:58] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[13:49:58] I/status - appium is not present
$/opt/google/chrome/chrome --version
Google Chrome 54.0.2840.59 unknown
```

How to debug this? What to do?

Comment: Take a screenshot when the exception occurs to understand why it's not clickable. It could be due to a fixed bar, a screen too small, an animation, a popup on top...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging "Element is not clickable at point" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error)